# p:graphicImage não exibe imagem

Tags: banco-de-dados, primefaces, front-end, back-end

Pessoal eu estou com problema para exibir uma imagem dentro do meu projeto em uma Data Table. Simplesmente a imagem fica em branco. O sistema faz uma consulta no banco mySQL do diretório da imagem para saber qual imagem representa o time específico. Este é o código para consultar:

```
    public ArrayList<Jogo> listarTodosBrasao() throws SQLException{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT j.id_jogo, j.dia, t_a.brasao, t_b.brasao FROM bolaodovibao.jogo j ");
    sql.append("INNER JOIN bolaodovibao.time t_a "); 
    sql.append("ON t_a.id_time=j.time_a "); 
    sql.append("INNER JOIN bolaodovibao.time t_b ");
    sql.append("ON t_b.id_time=j.time_b ORDER BY j.dia ASC ");

    Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<Jogo> lista = new ArrayList<Jogo>();

    while (resultado.next()) {
        Time time_a = new Time();
        time_a.setNome_time(resultado.getString("t_a.brasao"));

        Time time_b = new Time();
        time_b.setNome_time(resultado.getString("t_b.brasao"));

        Jogo jogo = new Jogo();
        jogo.setId_jogo(resultado.getInt("j.id_jogo"));
        jogo.setDia(resultado.getString("j.dia"));
        jogo.setTime_a(time_a);
        jogo.setTime_b(time_b);

        lista.add(jogo);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Este é o meu xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado." value="#{JogoMB.jogos}" 
    var="jogo" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="4" >
        <p:column headerText="Dia da Partida">
            <h:outputText value="#{jogo.dia}" ></h:outputText>
        </p:column> 

        <p:column headerText="Time A" >
            <p:graphicImage style="width: 80px; height: 80px;" value="#{jogo.time_a.brasao}" stream="false" />
        </p:column> 

        <p:column headerText="Time B" >
            <p:graphicImage style="width: 80px; height: 80px;" value="#{jogo.time_b.brasao}" stream="false" />
        </p:column> 

        <p:column headerText="Apostar" >
            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Apostar" />   
        </p:column> 
    </p:dataTable>
```

Esté o meu banco,id_time é PK e tem uma outra tabela no banco chamada JOGO que recebe PK como FK:

[image]

Resultado na tela:
[image]

Comment: Faça esse teste e veja se a imagem aparece:

Comment: Que teste Edjane?

Comment: Desculpa estava Editando! Faça esse teste e veja se a imagem aparece: <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pain.png" /> Nesse exemplo é pego a biblioteca images que tem que estar dentro de resources e como já é indicada a biblioteca é necessário somente indicar o nome do arquivo. Se os nomes de suas pastas estiverem corretos provavelmente esse teste irá funcionar, daí você verifica se realmente esta sendo chamado o endereço correto da imagem.

Comment: Está chamando, só não ta chamando quando eu mando um value="#{jogo.time_a.brasao}".

Comment: E quando você pesquisa time_a.brasao é chamado o endereço correto?

Comment: Sim, o resultado que saí do public ArrayList<Jogo> listarTodos() throws SQLException{ 

é este:

id=6, dia=2017-01-21, brasao=/resources/images/pain.png x brasao=/resources/images/pain.png,

Comment: Ver se trocando value por name dá certo name="#{jogo.time_b.brasao}"

Comment: Troque por name e deu erro 500: java.io.IOException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: Estranho ter dado esse erro, repliquei o seu problema aqui e também não consegui visualiza a imagem, vou tentar resolver esse problema daí te informo.

Comment: Agradeço Edjane :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como lhe disse anteriormente, repliquei a sua situação aqui usando maven, primefaces 6.0 e obtive o mesmo problema que você. O que acontece é que o GraphicImage faz duas requisições HTTP por imagem gerada. Li em alguns fóruns tratando essa forma do GraphicImage trabalhar como bug, mas não sei se é correto afirmar isso. Dá forma que trabalho com imagens no primefaces, não tive grandes problemas e acho bem mais tranquilo trabalhar assim, dessa forma declaro a biblioteca e o nome do arquivo vindo do banco de dados, veja o exemplo:

```
<p:column headerText="Imagem" style="text-align: center">
        <p:graphicImage library="img" name="#{imagem.nome}.png" width="120"
            url="http://suaPagina/seuProjeto">
        </p:graphicImage>
</p:column>
```

No caso acima a estrutura é:
/resources/img/nome.png

Encontrei uma forma de publicar a imagem usando value e solicitando o arquivo da pasta padrão resources. Fiz de duas formas, uma usando o primefaces e outra usando ominifaces, se você não conhece ominifaces dá uma olhada no site: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/ é mais uma opção de uma exelente biblioteca para trabalhar com páginas JSF.
Segue o exemplo do Bean:

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;
    import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
    import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

    @Named
    @RequestScoped
    public class ExemploRequestImagem {

        //usando ominifaces 
        public InputStream getImage() {
            return Faces.getResourceAsStream("/resources/img/large.jpg");
        }

        //usando primefaces
        public StreamedContent getImagem2() {
            InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/img/large.jpg");
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(input);
        }
    }
```

E o .xhtml fica assim:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="frmTeste">
    <p>
        <p:graphicImage style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" value="#{exemploRequestImagem.imagem2}">
        </p:graphicImage>
    </p>

    <p>
        <o:graphicImage style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"  value="#{exemploRequestImagem.image}" dataURI="true" />
    </p>

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Espero que isso ajude resolver o seu problema.